# How to remove the UIAlertview from mainview

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

In the application I'm developing I show an `UIAlertView`. Using an `NSTimer` I remove the alert calling the method `removeFromSuperView`. The alert is removed, but then any control works on the current view. Anyone can help me how to solve it? Here is my code to display alert:

```
UIAlertView *alert=[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"A" message:@"B" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeAlert:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And the method called by the timer:

```
-(void)removeAlert:(id)sender
{
    [alert_View removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: can you post some code my friend?

Comment: sdk : software devolopment kit. I dont think that is what you meant here.Please make the question clear.You can use the edit option to modify the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try below one line code

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

your problem will solve

Comment: No buttons on that alertview.

Comment: this line is correct. you don't need any buttons to perform this action. In it's super method it will dismiss the view and resett the "modal" flag, so you other view are also enabled for user interaction again :)

Comment: @user811598: no need of any button just put this code. instead of [alert_View removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 2):

Create your alert instant global by initiating it in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    UIAlertView *alert;
}
```

Then in .m file

```
//here use that instant variable alert
alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"A" message:@"B" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeAlert:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)removeAlert:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"hi dilip");
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];` instead of `[alert removeFromSuperView]` ;) it's a modal view, so you have to dismiss and not only to remove :)