# How to dismiss UIActionSheet or UIAlertView after the UIViewController popped

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uiactionsheet

In a situation, when UIAlertView or UIActionSheet is showing, due to some external event, I am supposed to pop the view controller, when I do so both alert view or Action sheet which is showing on the view is not destroying. As I am showing alerts view in many places I don't want to make it as member variable and dismiss by checking one by one.

How to handle this case? Any idea is really appreciated.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

for alertview you can use below answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915501/1713478

and for actionsheet use below code

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Please check the above comment.

Comment: means what you want exactly?

Comment: I tried to avoid adding UIAlertView as member variable. Without that I can't dismiss while pop.

Answer (score 0):

When view will popped then you need to dismiss alert or action sheet programmatically
You can use following methods:

```
myalert.delegate=nil;
[myalert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Same for Action sheet

Comment: If I'm showing 10 different messages in 10 cases... I have to make all 10 as member to dismiss... right?

Comment: No, You can iterate subviews of view in loop and can check kind of class,if it is action sheet or Alert then You can typecast object with appropriate class